# How to extract dvbsub teletext subtitles?

Tags: dvb

Does anyone know how to extract teletext subtitles?
I have tried ffmpeg, it says
Invalid frame dimensions 0x0

CCExtractor, it says
"Missing ASF header. Abort

telxcc, it says
! Invalid TS packet header; TS seems to be misaligned

I have done a lot of research, but have no luck. Can anyone offer some help!

Comment: invalid frame dimensions 0x0 typically means "packets before the first video frame" and can be benign

Answer (score 3):

dvb_subtitles cannot be extracted with ffmpeg easily because is an image that overlays the original. Good explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20887655/2119685

There is a way to extract the dvb_teletext, which normally includes the subtiltes too.

Install the next dependency:

```
sudo apt-get install libzvbi-dev
```

Then recompile from source ffmpeg with:

```
--enable-libzvbi
```

Good tutorial here on how to compile FFMPEG from source -https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu

Then execute the next command to fetch the subtitles to a .srt file:

```
ffmpeg -txt_format text -i INPUT1 -an -vn -scodec srt test.srt
```

And voila, your .srt subtitles will be in test.srt

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using gstreamer ? appsrc->tsdemux->fakesink. Make pipeline like this, and then get the PES data from fakesink callback.